# Firebase JWT: Signature verification failed

Tags: php, jwt, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use a JWT authentication with Firebase, but I got always this error: "Fatal error: Uncaught Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException: Signature verification failed".

The code is this:

```
$key = "test";

$tokenId    = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(32));
$issuedAt   = time();
$notBefore  = $issuedAt + 10;
$expire     = $notBefore + 60;
$serverName = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];


$data = [
    'iat'  => $issuedAt,
    'jti'  => $tokenId,
    'iss'  => $serverName,
    'nbf'  => $notBefore,
    'exp'  => $expire,
    "userId"  => 1
];


$secretKey = base64_decode($key);


$jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($data, $secretKey, 'HS256');

// and when I decode the tokens, I got that exception
$decoded = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

What I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `$secretKey` or base64_decode the key for that matter, just do:

```
$jwt = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode($data, $key, 'HS256');
$decoded = \Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
```

Comment: BTW one question (maybe not related to this question but I request you to please answer): I send 401 status code whenever the token is expired / Missing token in headers / Token is invalid. So the person who uses my APIs doesn't know how to handle this. For example he can't make difference if 401 was caused because of token related issue or something else. How should we handle it?