# why I get this error " Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' with message 'Signature verification failed'"

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

I get a token and I need to decode it. Using JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256')) always generate an error. ( error in signature check )

I found some post but they are not solving my problem ( [Firebase JWT: Signature verification failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706881/firebase-jwt-signature-verification-failed) for ex. there are others but no solutions is working). I guess I'm missing something very basic here. I tried as well URL64 decode/encode ..Etc.. with my token but I'm still unable to get it decoded  properly. When I use JWT.io, token is decrypted without any problem.
Where am I missing something in the code below ?

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
$jwt = "eyJraWQiOiJUUyIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJsaW9uZWwiLCJvcCI6ImF1dGgiLCJsdmwiOjEsImRzaWQiOiJhZTk0ZjdiOC03YzliLTRlYWUtOTZhNy04ZjAxZWEwNTQxOTEiLCJpc3MiOiJUUyIsInBpZCI6ImxvZ2luIiwicGFyYW1zIjp7fSwic2lkIjoiODFhNmVmNWYtZjhhZi00ODk4LWIyZmUtYWM1OTBhZDQyYWEzIiwiYXVkIjoid2ViYXBwIiwicHZpZCI6InN0YXRpYyIsImV4cCI6MTU3MzAzNjUxMCwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDM0NzEwLCJqdGkiOiIzMmM4Y2YxZi0wYTE3LTQ3ZTUtOWVhNi05ZTRlZDlhZTQ4NTAiLCJkaWQiOiIxZTdjMDQwZC01ZGM5LTRlMzktYjBjYy0wMjUwZTI4ZjY0MDQifQ.KU9dpKENm1_YmBngCEnXP2XiGpCkA7sf5pmojB7TzKM";
$key = "secret";


print_r("JWT\n\n");
print_r($jwt);

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));
echo "DECODED\n";
print_r($decoded);


?>
```

the code generates this error :

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException' with message 'Signature verification failed' in /var/www/html/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:112

Thx

Comment: "token is decrypted without any problem" - the token is not encrypted, but just base64url encoded. But when I try your token as posted above with the secret "secret" jwt.io can't verify it. Make sure you have the correct secret and see if you can verify on jwt.io (by pasting the token into the field in the right column under "Verify signature".

Comment: is this not what I should do ? here is a screenshot of the result https://ibb.co/bWL7bND

Comment: yes, but look at the signature in the screenshot (the blue characters in the left column). It's not the same as posted in your question. So the token and secret in your code exampel above don't match. Take the token that you have show in the screenshot and try to verify it in your code, that should work.

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: nope, I rechecked everything to be sure. I have this token ( a new one ) : eyJraWQiOiJUUyIsImFsZyI6IkhTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJsaW9uZWwiLCJvcCI6ImF1dGgiLCJsdmwiOjEsImRzaWQiOiI2NmE0NGEzNy1iN2Q2LTQwZWEtYjMyNi1kMGRiYjAzNDUzZTIiLCJpc3MiOiJUUyIsInBpZCI6ImxvZ2luIiwicGFyYW1zIjp7fSwic2lkIjoiNjg3YTBhNDctYzVjNC00MDg1LTg4NmUtM2I5YmFkN2IzMzBkIiwiYXVkIjoid2ViYXBwIiwicHZpZCI6InN0YXRpYyIsImV4cCI6MTU3MzIwNjU4MywiaWF0IjoxNTczMjA0NzgzLCJqdGkiOiJmNDUyYjU1OS1jZjg1LTRkNjYtYmQ4Ny1kOGM1NzY3NmUzOGEiLCJkaWQiOiIxZTdjMDQwZC01ZGM5LTRlMzktYjBjYy0wMjUwZTI4ZjY0MDQifQ.nPUF1T30IsBppvgFd9UayRRlquNgqfoOUa7f4KOubF0. Paste it into

Comment: jwt.io , it says "wrong signature", when I click on "secret base64 encoded ", it switches to signature verified. I don't understand.

Comment: The "trick" on jwt.io is, that you ***first*** paste the secret into the field in the right column and then paste the token, which you want to verify , into the left column. Then you see if get's verified or not. If you change the secret ***after*** you paste the token (and clicking on 'secret base64 encoded' is a change) then jwt.io recalculates the signature (the blue characters after the last dot) and says it's verified. First make sure you have a token that is verified by jwt.io, then try that token and secret in your code. If jwt.io fails to verify it, your code should of course fail too.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the trick and I confirm it is not working. let's solve this with JWT.io first. Thx !